# Parsing json to model fails in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show data to listview but it doesn't show anything.there is json below ,am i doing something wrong,i tired to print the data in api call but i can print the data but not in the listview,
i having hardtime to understand what i doing wrong or correct.please help me on this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        if (status == true) {

          var company_list = value['doc'];
          for (int i = 0; i < company_list.length; i++) {
            print(company_list);
            var mobile_list = company_list["mobile"];
            var email_list = company_list["email"];
            company_model.add(CompanyModel.fromJson(company_list,mobile_list,email_list));
          }
          setState(() {
            print("UI Updated");
          });
        } else {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
      }
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
```

Json

```
{
    "status":true,
    "doc":{
        "mobile":[
            "9961256754",
            "8974525672"
        ],
        "email":[

        ],
        "_id":"5f3a0dfe88b9d50453e92133",
        "name":"MRC Labour",
        "terms":{
            "english":"We Shall not be liable for any disputes arising between the users and the 
         labourers",
            "malayalam":"We Shall not be liable for any disputes arising between the users and the 
         labourers"
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class CompanyModel {
  String id = "";
  String mobile = "";
  String email = "";
  String name = "";
  String english = "";
  String malayalam = "";

  CompanyModel({this.id, this.mobile, this.email, this.name, this.english,this.malayalam});

  CompanyModel.fromJson(json,mobile_list,email_list)
      : id = json['_id'].toString(),
        mobile = mobile_list,
        email = email_list,
        name = json['name'].toString(),
        english = json['terms']['english'].toString(),
        malayalam = json['terms']['malayalam'].toString();
}
```

[image: Data i am geting,]

When the debugger hit at this line it breaks without any errors `company_model.add(CompanyModel.fromJson(data,mobile_list,email_list));`

This is listview code

```
   Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView.separated(
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            const Divider(),
            itemCount: company_model.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              CompanyModel data = company_model[index];
              print(data);
              return Container(
                height: 10,
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text(data.name.toString(),style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Doesn't your logcat tell you something?

Comment: how are you initializing the `company_model`  variable? Can you add the part of the code that you initialize it?

Comment: company_list is not a list it's a JSON and you are iterating it.

Comment: it just a temporary name@DarshanPrajapati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your model is wrong, you're parsing a List (mobile and email) as a String in your model, also, you don't really need to pass 2 additional parameters to the function.

```
class CompanyModel {
  List<String> mobile;
  List<String> email;
  String sId;
  String name;
  Terms terms;

  CompanyModel({this.mobile, this.email, this.sId, this.name, this.terms});

  CompanyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    mobile = json['mobile'].cast<String>();
    email = json['email'].cast<String>();
    sId = json['_id'];
    name = json['name'];
    terms = json['terms'] != null ? new Terms.fromJson(json['terms']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['mobile'] = this.mobile;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    if (this.terms != null) {
      data['terms'] = this.terms.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Terms {
  String english;
  String malayalam;

  Terms({this.english, this.malayalam});

  Terms.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    english = json['english'];
    malayalam = json['malayalam'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['english'] = this.english;
    data['malayalam'] = this.malayalam;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Also, double check that you're initializing the `company_model` as something like: `List company_model = []` otherwise it initialize as `null`  and won't work the rest of your code.

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        if (status == true) {

          var company_json = value['doc'];
          company_model.add(CompanyModel.fromJson(company_json));
          setState(() {
            print("UI Updated");
          });
        } else {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
      }
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message));
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
```

Comment: this how i initialized  company_model  ` List<CompanyModel> company_model = [];` @Vitor

Comment: @MorbiusBlack that's right, it will work fine I think, try the code that I posted and then tell me the results ;)

Comment: when print `company_json` in for loop it prints data but still i cannot access the data to listview,i have  added the listview code ,please look into it @Vitor

Comment: what is printing here?  `CompanyModel data = company_model[index]; print(data);`

Comment: nothing printing here,i think no data passed to model @Vitor

Comment: @MorbiusBlack are you getting any errors? if so, update your question with the errors that you're getting now. Also, check if the `print("UI Updated")` is being called. If so, try to print the `company_model.length` and check if there's more than 1 item. Also, try my answer now, I've updated the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219971/discussion-between-vitor-and-morbius-black).

Comment: not it's not calling `print("UI Updated")` ,there is only 1 item.this is what i am retrving from company_json `{mobile: [9961256754, 8974525672], email: [], _id: 5f3a0dfe88b9d50453e92133, name: MRC Labour, terms: {english: We Shall not be liable for any disputes arising between the users and the labourers, malayalam: നിങ്ങളും തൊഴിലാളികളും തമ്മിലുള്ള പ്രശ്നങ്ങൾക്ക് ആപ് ഉടമകളോ ആപ് നിർമാതാക്കളോ ഉത്തരവാദിയായിരിക്കുന്നതല്ല}}` @Vitor

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create model is in the link below
https://app.quicktype.io/

just put your json on as input on left side and select dart as language from left, you are good to go.